# Meaning of "Running" time field in Results and correlation with the "shots" choosen number

Tags: ibm-q-experience, speedup

I've created a same circuit that I've executed two different ways on the same computer (ibmq_16_melbourne); First with 1024 Shots and secondly with 8096 Shots

For the first (1024), I got in results, a "Running" time of 8.8s 
For the second (8096), I got in results, a "Running" time of 35.7s

What does this "Running" field means exactly? Is it not a running execution time on the quantum computer?

If so, normally, I should got about 70 seconds for the second way. 
Why is it shorter?

Thank you for your help & answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing run times on IBM Quantum Experience](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/3901/comparing-run-times-on-ibm-quantum-experience)

Comment: Thank you, but Unfortunately not.

Comment: I try to understand the correlation between the number of shots and the execution time. What is the relation, if there is one ? What is sure is that , the more shots (re-execution of your algorithm) you do, the better probability values you get. And normally the execution time is expected to be proportional to the number of shots, at the error ready ... but not but not from simple to double :)

Comment: As mentioned in the answer there, there are overhead times such as loading the experiment which are constant for both executions. The time for actually running your program should then scale with the number of shots :)